# get a fast String input in android

Tags: android, string, performance, input

I'm looking for a fast way to get an input String from the user in Android.
For example in java the code:

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter your input");`

gets the input from the user. I'm looking such this thing in Android.

Answer (score 4):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setMessage("Message");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
  String value = input.getText();
  // Do something with value!
  }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // Canceled.
  }
});

alert.show();
```

Comment: I had to modify this |String value = input.getText();| to |String value = (input.getText()).toString();| or else Eclipse gave me the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Editable to String".